# shapeBody.setFillColor not working (from Anylogic in 3 days book)

Tags: anylogic

So I am following along with the example Market model in the "Anylogic in 3 days" eBook.

It says to create a state and set the On Enter action to this:

```
shapeBody.setFillColor(lavender);
```

All I get is this:

```
Description: shapeBody cannot be resolved. Location: Market/Consumer/PotentialUser - State
```

I have tried:

```
person.setFillColor(lavender);
```

but then I just get:

```
Description: The method setFillColor(Color) is undefined for the type Shape3DObject. Location: Market/Consumer/User - State
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sequence of errors, I am guessing your mistake is that you are using the 3D shape person and not the 2D one (left vs. right in the below picture).

[image]

Anyway, the 2D shape (black icon) is a group of shapes. If you click on it twice (wait between the two clicks), you will see that a shape within the group called "ShapeBody" is selected. This is what the book's function is accessing.

Comment: Indeed I was, many thanks.   I missed a step